# How to change the value of an attribute programmatically?

Tags: css, dart

Sorry. Still a beginner. Had a look around and couldn't find an appropriate answer (probably because I'm using the wrong terms!). 
In my CSS file I have

```
[pcolor="teapot"]{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
[pcolor="kettle"]{
    background-color: #ff4440;
}
[pcolor="pan"]{
   background-color: #0044ff;
}
```

1) How do I change the color of (eg) "teapot"?  (I'm using Dart. I want the user to be able to change the color at runtime).
2) How can I add another attribute "bottle" (again, at run time) ?
3) Can I delete them at runtime?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you map an attribute's value to a color. So either you predefine all available colors (which is a lot and thus bad) or you simple overwrite the background color attribute. I do NOT recommend to change/add/delete CSS at runtime, which you could achieve with `<style>` elements. A better way follows here:

In Dart (and JavaScript as well) you can use the element's style attribute to access the element's CSS. You can just go ahead and do:

```
Element e = ...;
e.style.backgroundColor = '#f01251';
```

This way the element's style overwrites the color from the attribute. So you don't even have to remove the pcolor attribute. You can simply overwrite new colors to `e.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I understand your answer - it's what I do at the moment. But I have elements throughout my code that need to be set. I was trying to avoid setting the backgroundColor for these elements, because I have to add a line before each one to get the color. I just want all elements with "kettle" to be set to an attribute/class (or some selector) which I change at one location, and all element colors will change to the new setting.  Maybe it's not an attribute I should be using...? Cheers, Steve

Comment: Ok. I get your point, but, you could do: `querySelectorAll('[attr]').forEach((Element e) { e.style.backgroundColor = '...'; });`. Or create a custom element using Polymer and put them into a list and call a method on them.